# PSR12 Allow newline after closing parenthesis

Tags: php, phpcs, psr-12

How can I **allow** the writing of the bellow code? which rules should I add to my custom ruleset xml?

```
foreach ($mIn as $key => $value)
{
    $mOut -> $key = $mIn -> $key;
}
```

currently, PHPCS is issuing a warning stating that a space is expected after the closing parenthesis but instead finds a new line.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably look at [these rules](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/src/Standards/PSR12/ruleset.xml#L211) and find the right one to ingore